# org.w3c.dom.Document undo in java

Tags: java, w3c, batik

Is it possible to apply an `UndoManager()` to an `org.w3c.dom.Document`? If not, is there any way for undo / redo an `org.w3c.dom.Document`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what undo/redo mean in dom ??

Comment: Hi
javax.swing has an undo manager, in order to apply undo / redo actions (text or properties changed, etc.). I would know if it's possible in a Batik JSvgDocument (SVG).
Thanks, Niks

Comment: i m really unaware abt it.

Answer (score 0):

The DOM has no built-in undo mechanism. If you want that, your application has to figure out how to provide it.

Comment: Thanks, jeshlam. I'm lookig for it, with DOM mutation events, but it's very difficult for me to find appropiate docs.

Comment: If you have specific questions about the DOM, post 'em and I'll see what I can do to clarify matters.

Comment: Thanks keshlam. I will prepare the questions